# get 'Invalid Login credentials' logging into RedHat Fuse Management Console 7

Tags: jboss, redhat, jbossfuse

my environment:
Ubuntu - clean install
JDK 11 Oracle
Jboss EAP 7.4  (installed in /var/jboss/EAP)
Fuse 7.12

Running standalone.sh

access console locally at localhost:8080/hawtio

tried Jboss admin user that works at localhost:9990
tried adding user with /var/jboss/EAP/bin/add-user.sh
tried with openjdk

'invalid login credentials' every time

Answer (score 1):

I have just tried Fuse 7.12 on EAP 7.4.12 and it worked well as expected.

I used `openjdk version "11.0.17"` on MacOS

Have you tried the exact steps as below?

1. Unzip jboss-eap-7.4 archive
2. Run `java -jar <fuse_eap_installer>.jar jboss-eap-7.4.Z.zip`
3. Add a new user by running `jboss-eap-7.4/bin/add-user.sh`
4. Make sure you add the user properly (roles, passwords, etc.)
5. Change a directory `cd jboss-eap-7.4/standalone/configuration`
6. Run EAP with desired configs (e.g. `../../bin/standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml`)
7. Access HawtIO `localhost:8080/hawtio` and log in

Let me know whether it helps.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Hawtio v2 doesn't support the new Elytron securty subsystem:
https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/issues/2709

If you'd like to use Hawtio with a newer version of EAP or WildFly, please disable authentication by configuring:

```
hawtio.authenticationEnabled = false
```